# Unable to perform query on AWS athena using Golang SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I am new to AWS and Golang, and I am trying to create a lambda function, which will trigger AWS Athena query and email the result using AWS SES service. Even after searching for an hour, I couldn't find a working example of lambda function (in Golang) to perform a query on Athena and getting the output of the query.

While searching, I found code for the same in Java, Python and Node Js, but not in Golang.

Even the [Go-SDK page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/athena/#Athena.ListNamedQueries) redirects to Java example. But unfortunately, I don't even understand Java.

I have also looked into this [AWS SDK for Go API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/) page. But I don't understand what is the flow of the program and which operation to select.

I have tried to create the program for this, this may be completely wrong, and I don't know what to do next. Below is the code -

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/athena"
)

func main() {

    // Create a new session in the us-west-2 region.
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1")},
    )

    // Create an Athena session.
    client := athena.New(sess)

    // Example sending a request using the StartQueryExecutionRequest method.
    query := "SELECT * FROM table1 ;"
    params := query
    req, resp := client.StartQueryExecutionRequest(params)

    err1 := req.Send()
    if err1 == nil { // resp is now filled
        fmt.Println(resp)
    }
}
```

Appreciate if someone can help me to perform an Athena query and to get its result in Golang(Preferably) or can share some resource. Once I get it, I can then send an email using AWS SES.

Comment: Have you looked at this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-programming-model-handler-types.html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to get started.

```
// run as: go run main.go
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/endpoints"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/external"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/athena"
)

const table = "textqldb.textqltable"
const outputBucket = "s3://bucket-name-here/"

func main() {

    cfg, err := external.LoadDefaultAWSConfig()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("config error: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    cfg.Region = endpoints.UsEast2RegionID

    client := athena.New(cfg)

    query := "select * from " + table

    resultConf := &athena.ResultConfiguration{
        OutputLocation: aws.String(outputBucket),
    }

    params := &athena.StartQueryExecutionInput{
        QueryString:         aws.String(query),
        ResultConfiguration: resultConf,
    }

    req := client.StartQueryExecutionRequest(params)

    resp, err := req.Send(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("query error: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can add some comments in the code.

Comment: Currently, the query results are getting stored on S3. But I want to consume the result directly and email it using SES. Is it possible? Otherwise, I will have to fetch the result back from S3 and then email it.

Comment: Just want to add for others, while running the code initially I got this error - "cannot find package "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/github.com/aws". Which is resolved by below command - "go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/". For more info see - https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2

Comment: I think that Athena query results must be issued to S3. But you can check the SDK documentation: https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/athena#ResultConfiguration

Comment: You should not need to run "go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws" if you are using Go 1.13.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your comments. I will check the SDK documentation.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer if it addressed your question.

Answer (score 1):

@Everton's code is executing a query on Athena, and its responses are getting saved on S3 bucket and not getting returned. So, I have added the code to execute the Athena query and get the response back. Hope this may help others.

```
// run as: go run main.go
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/endpoints"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/external"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/athena"
)

const table = "<Database_Name>.<Table_Name>"
const outputBucket = "s3://bucket-name-here/"

// Execute the query and return the query ID
func executeQuery(query string) *string {

    cfg, err := external.LoadDefaultAWSConfig()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("config error: %v\n", err)
    }

    cfg.Region = endpoints.UsEast2RegionID

    client := athena.New(cfg)

    resultConf := &athena.ResultConfiguration{
        OutputLocation: aws.String(outputBucket),
    }

    params := &athena.StartQueryExecutionInput{
        QueryString:         aws.String(query),
        ResultConfiguration: resultConf,
    }

    req := client.StartQueryExecutionRequest(params)

    resp, err := req.Send(context.TODO())
    fmt.Println("Response is: ", resp, " Error is:", err)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Query Error: %v\n", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Query Execution Response ID:", resp.QueryExecutionId)
    return resp.QueryExecutionId
}

// Takes queryId as input and returns its response
func getQueryResults(QueryID *string) (*athena.GetQueryResultsResponse, error) {

    cfg, err := external.LoadDefaultAWSConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic("config error")
    }

    cfg.Region = endpoints.UsEast2RegionID
    client := athena.New(cfg)
    params1 := &athena.GetQueryResultsInput{
        QueryExecutionId: QueryID,
    }
    req := client.GetQueryResultsRequest(params1)

    resp, err := req.Send(context.TODO())

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Query Response Error: %v\n", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    return resp, nil

}

func main() {

    query := "select * from " + table

    // Execute an Athena Query
    QueryID := executeQuery(query)


    // Get the response of the query

    // Wait for some time for query completion
    time.Sleep(15 * time.Second) // Otherwise create a loop and try for every x seconds
    Resp, err := getQueryResults(QueryID)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error getting Query Response: %v\n", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(" \nRows:", Resp.ResultSet.Rows)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wonder

- Waiting for query execution
- How to get data from query result
- How to handle the query result that have more pages

Sample Code, using **aws-sdk-go-v2**

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "context"
  "time"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/athena"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/athena/types"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
)

const REGION = "ap-southeast-1"
const QUERY = "SELECT * FROM sampletable"
const OUTPUT_BUCKET = "s3://athena-result-output-bucket"

func main() {

  cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), func(o *config.LoadOptions) error {
    o.Region = REGION
    return nil
  })

  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }

  client := athena.NewFromConfig(cfg)

  resultConfig := &types.ResultConfiguration{
    OutputLocation: aws.String(OUTPUT_BUCKET),
  }

  executeParams := &athena.StartQueryExecutionInput{
    QueryString: aws.String(QUERY),
    ResultConfiguration: resultConfig,
  }

  // Start Query Execution
  athenaExecution, err := client.StartQueryExecution(context.TODO(), executeParams)


  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }

  // Get Query execution and check for the Query state constantly every 2 second
  executionId := *athenaExecution.QueryExecutionId

  for {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

    status, stateErr := client.GetQueryExecution(context.TODO(), &athena.GetQueryExecutionInput{
      QueryExecutionId: &executionId,
    })

    if stateErr != nil {
      fmt.Println(stateErr)
      return
    }

    state := status.QueryExecution.Status.State


    if state == types.QueryExecutionStateSucceeded || state == types.QueryExecutionStateCancelled {
      break
    } else if state == types.QueryExecutionStateFailed {
      fmt.Println("Query Execution failed")
      return
    }
  }


  // Get Query result 

  queryParams := &athena.GetQueryResultsInput{
    QueryExecutionId: &executionId,
  }

  for {

    result, getQueryErr := client.GetQueryResults(context.TODO(), queryParams)

    if getQueryErr != nil {
      fmt.Println(getQueryErr)
      return
    }

    // Get data from query result
    for rowIndex, row := range result.ResultSet.Rows {
      // first row are the Column name
      if rowIndex == 0 {
        continue
      }

      // Display Column data
      fmt.Printf("Col1: %v, Col2: %v \n", *row.Data[0].VarCharValue, *row.Data[1].VarCharValue)
    }
    

    // If NO more next page result set
    if result.NextToken == nil {
      break
    }

    queryParams.NextToken = result.NextToken
  }
}
```